# carmack's invsqrt in asm

Tags: c, optimization, assembly, x86, fpu

Hullo, I am not too much experienced in asm and I would like
to rewrite carmack's inverted square root c routine in assembly

```
    ;   float InvSqrt (float x){
    ;
    @173:
    push      ebp
    mov       ebp,esp
    add       esp,-8
    ;
    ;       float xhalf = 0.5f*x;
    ;
    fld       dword ptr [@174]
    fmul      dword ptr [ebp+8]
    fstp      dword ptr [ebp-4]
    ;
    ;       int i = *(int*)&x;
    ;
    mov       eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]
    mov       dword ptr [ebp-8],eax
    ;
    ;       i = 0x5f3759df - (i>>1);
    ;
    mov       edx,dword ptr [ebp-8]
    sar       edx,1
    mov       ecx,1597463007
    sub       ecx,edx
    mov       dword ptr [ebp-8],ecx
    ;
    ;       x = *(float*)&i;
    ;
    mov       eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]
    mov       dword ptr [ebp+8],eax
    ;
    ;       x = x*(1.5f - xhalf*x*x);
    ;
   fld       dword ptr [ebp-4]
   fmul      dword ptr [ebp+8]
   fmul      dword ptr [ebp+8]
   fsubr     dword ptr [@174+4]
   fmul      dword ptr [ebp+8]
   fstp      dword ptr [ebp+8]
   ;
   ;        return x;
   ;
   fld       dword ptr [ebp+8]
   ;
   ;    }
   ;
   @176:
   @175:
    pop       ecx
    pop       ecx
    pop       ebp
    ret
```

here was what compiler generated, but I would like to optimise it 
and rewrite to asm routine

(this code generated is far from optimal i thing - mixing fpu with integer
operations, maybe some revrite by conscious person would much improve it)

how it can be optymized?

edit:

as to answer @harold

there is an improvement:

- 1.0/sqrt(100.0) takes 140 cycles on my old machine
- InvSqrt - c version - takes 44 cycles (though accuracy is not stunning)
- ansver below in asm works same as c version and it takes 29 cycles

(measurments may be somewhat approximate but genarlly seem be ok IMO, 
 done by rtdsc 1000x for loop then resulting 140000/1000 = 140cycles 
29000/1000 = 29cycles and so)

Comment: Did you try, first, to use the *optimization* options offered by your compiler (e.g. `gcc -O3 ...` for gcc)?

Comment: want to lern hand assembly, but would like some help with that (I am not to much experienced in asm by now)

Comment: This is a small routine that makes a lot of use of the math-processor - I'm not sure there is much room left for optimization. Anyway, you could generate the asm code with `-O3` and see the difference.

Comment: @grungefightr, starts somewhere simple, e.g. look at the assembly for `int return1() { return 1; }` and `int returnx(int x) { return x; }` and `void loop() { int i = 0; while ( i < 10) { i++; } }` and `void add(int x, int y) { x+y; }` and so on.

Comment: @up I know simple assembly but do not know harder things like what kind of rewrite it would speed it up

Comment: Why on earth would you write this in assembly?  If you're writing assembly, you use the `rsqrtss` instruction, which is vastly simpler, faster, and more accurate.

Comment: @up on newest procesors - I want code to work on older too

Comment: SSE instructions ara available since Pentium III (introduced in 1999), and old AMD CPUs have a similar instruction, PFRSQRT in 3dnow! (since 1998). Similar instructions exist in ARM ISA. Carmack's invsqrt algorithm was designed when the first Pentium was the top CPU, and it is not efficient on modern processors: reading quadword just after writing it as two doublewords is very slow (google "store forwarding stalls").

Comment: ok, probably will use sse finally, but i want to try and measure this one also (for experience and learning purposes)

Comment: You do know that this is actually much *slower* than the straightforward approach on modern CPU's, right? It was used *many* years ago because back then, mainstream processors had different performance characteristics. On today's CPU's, it will slow down your code, not speed it up...

Comment: @jalf so what's "modern" then? IMO a Core2 65nm is modern enough, but `fsqrt` still has a worst case of 69 cycles. On anything newer than that, square root and division have gotten substantially faster, but a Core2 65nm isn't all *that* old..

Comment: @harold: what does `fsqrt` have to do with anything? The question is about *inverse* square root, which SSE can do out of the box :)

Comment: @jalf yes I would recommend that myself, but he doesn't want to use SSE..

Comment: okay i will use reciprocal probably but just wanted to test it out, many times i want to do something people come and say to me that i should not  ;-) - it is not so wise, really, I just want to check some things, so tnx to harold for answr

Comment: @harold which is why I merely asked him if he was aware that what he was doing is a waste of time performance-wise :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of those moves to/from memory aren't really necessary. This probably isn't *too* much of an improvement though (especially not compared to not doing any of this in the first place and just using SSE).

Not tested:

```
; i = 0x5f3759df - (reinterpret_cast<int32>(number) >> 1)
mov eax, dword ptr [ebp+8]
sar eax,1
mov edx, 0x5f3759df
sub edx, eax
mov dword ptr [ebp-4], edx
; y = reinterpret_cast<float>(i)
fld dword ptr [ebp-4]
; x2 = numer * 0.5f
fld dword ptr [ebp+8]
fmul dword ptr [half]
; (x2 * y) * y
fmul st(0), st(1)
fmul st(0), st(1)
; 1.5f - (stuff)
fld dword ptr [threehalfs]
fsubrp st(1), st(0)
; y * (stuff)
fmulp st(1), st(0)
```

It shouldn't really be too hard to follow, but I'll make some stack diagrams if you want them.

Comment: tnx :P I will try It, will back l8er a while after testing and measuring to say if it was improvement

Comment: got one question, though, -- I use NASM, how i can prepare .5 half and 1.5 threehalf to use here? I do not know how to do it, can you maybe show it ? - full code with .5 1.5 involved in asm routine?? much tnx

Comment: @grungefightr you can declare them with dd, just like integers really

Comment: And when i need tu use local float it is sufficient when i wrtote push ebp \ mov ebp, esp \ add esp, -4 \ ...... \ mov esp, ebp \ pop ebp \ ret - as a prologue epilogue ?

Comment: @grungefightr that looks fine

Comment: allrite, (tired now will back with a new quest some time;)

Comment: Just to expand on what Harold says... "dd 1" is an integer, "dd 1.0" is a float. The presence of the decimal point is how Nasm knows you want a float.

Comment: alrite, will test it soon, tnx

Comment: tested - works ok and there is 15 cycles (30%) speedup ( kool ) (see edit block in question )

Comment: @grungefightr not bad, that's better than I expected. You could even add a second refinement step and come out much faster than 140 cycles (but with not so bad accuracy). Or I could do that, if you'd like.

Comment: If you like - I think In my simple raytracer I do not need very good accuracy so I will test if it gives good visible effects - as to accuracy invsqrt(100.) yeilds here 0.0998448 - Also tried do not use local variable and use gloabal one (to spare add esp, -4 ... mov esp, ebp) but suprisingly it was not faster but slower about one cycle

Comment: Yet one doubt question - need I use here fwait somewhere? I do not fully understand this fwait questions :-/

Comment: @grungefightr `fwait` is mostly of historical interest, when the fpu was a separate processor. There are still some rare cases where it is useful, but as a general rule you never need it on Pentiums or newer.